# Custom Built Computer - Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10 Install Fails

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, ssd, bios, ahci

I just built a computer with the following:

```
Gigabyte Z68A Motherboard
Corsair Force GT 180GB SSD
GeForce GT430 Graphics card
Corsair TX750 Watt Power supply
Intel i5 CPU
```

My problem when trying to install Windows 7 is that it keeps asking me where it can find the driver that can format my SSD. However, my BIOS can see the SSD and I have set it to `AHCI`. I can't find a driver for my SSD though, but this (apparently) should not be happening.

My problem when trying to install Ubuntu 11.10 is that the install screen never loads.

I have burned both operating systems to DVDs in order to install.

What should I do? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try starting the Ubuntu install process without the SSD just to check if this is the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the firmware of your SSD. That might help. The latest version for your SSD is 1.3.3. All the information and firmware software can be found at the manufacturers website:

http://www.corsair.com/ssd/force-series-gt-ssd/force-series-gt-180gb-sata-3-6gbps-solid-state-hard-drive.html